# Powershell Parallel Processing issue

Tags: powershell, parallel-processing

I get the following error:  The term 'Create-FacilityCSV' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable  program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try  again. I have searched for the above error and it points to a .source issue but I can run the function when its included in the same file or .source but when I try to parallel process it I get the error.

I can run this code without issue

```
foreach ($d in $directory_info) {
  cd $d
  Create-FacilityCSV
  cd ..
} #end foreach
```

But when I use this

```
# Parallel process this job
    Start-Job -Name CSV -ScriptBlock {
      param ([string[]]$directory_info)
        foreach ($d in $directory_info) {
        cd $d
        Create-FacilityCSV
        cd ..
        } #end foreach
    } -ArgumentList (,$directory_info)
```

I get the above error. Suggestions?  Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use initialization script for passing the function inside the start-job scriptblock like this:

```
$a={
    function Create-FacilityCSV(){
        # Paste the Create-FacilityCSV fucntion code
       }
}
    Start-Job -InitializationScript $a -Name CSV -ScriptBlock {
      param ([string[]]$directory_info)
        foreach ($d in $directory_info) {
        cd $d
        Create-FacilityCSV
        cd ..
        } #end foreach
    } -ArgumentList (,$directory_info)
```

Here is **one simple example on how to pass it**:

```
$ini='$var="'+$args[0]+'"'
$a={
 Function Get-add()
        {
        "this  is the value of $var"

        }
 }
start-job -InitializationScript $a -ScriptBlock {param($ini)iex $ini;get-add } -ArgumentList $ini |Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```

Comment: Thank You both for the quick responses.  This worked perfectly, once I solved some other issues.  But I went from a 10 minute process to 1. I also have 4 kids and hard to get to work on the weekend.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell jobs run in separate processes, so this is expected. Where is `Create-FacilityCSV` defined? You'll have to re-define it inside the scriptblock for the job, or ideally put it in a module and import the module inside the scriptblock.